# What kind of 4pin connector is this?

Tags: connector

I was replacing my thermostat, and was dumb and didn’t shut off power. I checked all the fuses on my trane air handler, and replaced 1 blown one. Still didn’t work. Called an hvac company and I got the impression they have no clue what they were doing. They check all the wires for continuity, all were fine, but one. Going from a display/control panel to another circuit board. The hvac guy said the wire sold by trane was out of stock, he’s also tryna charge me 100$ for “labor” + cost of the wire. The wire is very generic looking, but I’m not sure what it’s called. If any of you know, that would be great, considering I’m in newjersey and it’s very very humid, hot, and Smokey (from the Canada fires) and I don’t prefer to roast. (Photos are from the hvac guy, sorry about low quality/angle. [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please measure the pitch accurately and report it in mm. Please post a decent picture of the female plug, from different angles. Please post a decent picture of the male PCB header, so we can see some detail.

Comment: Are you planning to replace this part on your own?  Seems you already have money invested in the repair, (or at least the diagnosis).  If it is really just an open wire then it is likely open near the edge of one of the crimped metal contacts.  If you own (or are willing to buy a $15 DVM) you could check the pin to pin continuity and maybe even repair it yourself.  Some of these connectors can even have the pin connections repaired if you very carefully remove the pin.  (Also be careful that the repair person didn't over look a loose pin on the PCB.)

Comment: If there was an over current condition, (that burnt the fuse), then you might look for one of the wires being overheated or burned.  Sometimes the pin inside the housing heats up and melts some of the plastic, that can result in a poor contact.

Answer (score 1):

If the pitch is 2 mm, then that's a [Molex Sherlock](https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/part-detail/353620450) or an [Adam Tech 2SH](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/adam-tech/2SH-H-04-TS/10414783).

If the pitch is 2.5 mm, then that's a [JST XA](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/index.php?series=272).

Please measure the [pitch](https://www.google.com/search?q=connector+pitch) accurately, so we can tell which.